# Can devenv.exe build support multilple config in one command build?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution with two projects (2018 and 2019). Each project has two release config for basic version and a pro versoin.

The command line to build the whole thing for release is

```
devenv ForCmdBuild_u2018.sln /Build Release_Pro
devenv ForCmdBuild_u2018.sln /Build Release
devenv ForCmdBuild_u2019.sln /Build Release_Pro
devenv ForCmdBuild_u2019.sln /Build Release
```

Although it works perfectly fine, the /Build commmand seem only support a single config which cause the visual studio to load/unload 4 times which is quite slow. I wonder if I can make it a single call and reduce the waiting time.

Comment: "which cause the visual studio to load/unload 4 times"? VS doesn't really load if you use it to build a solution. Do you really see a window opening?

Comment: It doesn't matter if VS loaded or not. My focus is the warm-up time which takes like 10+ seconds every time before a build begins. If I can make it in 1 command, I could save a lot of time. The project compile in 1-2 sec in VisualStudio UI.